# Microsoft Excel 2007 - How do I write a dynamic Table_Array for Vlookup

Tags: vba, excel, dynamic, vlookup

I'm not sure if I need to post this question in a specific place, but here goes.

*WARNING: Wall of text. I need to explain my situation fully as it appears to be a unique problem with not many solutions.*

TL;DR - Master spreadsheet grabs data from "weekly" spreadsheet via vlookups. A new spreadsheet is released every week. How do I automate the vlookup to grab data from a new spreadsheet, every week?

Now here is the long version...

I have a master spreadsheet that uses vlookups pointing to another spreadsheet. Example code below:

`=VLOOKUP(A2,'...OTC\2016\Reports Sent\[SALES BY SKU  STORE wk 3  (retail) (2).xls]SKU'!$D$1:$G$65536,4,FALSE)`

Great. Easy Peasy.

The master spreadsheet is currently pointing to data for "Week 3". Hence, [SALES BY SKU STORE **wk3** (retail)(2).xls]. Currently in the file directory, where the spreadsheet lives, week 3 spreadsheet is the most up-to-date. Every week, a new spreadsheet will be saved in the same folder but called [SALES BY SKU STORE **wk4** (retail)(2).xls]. Getting the idea now..?

I want the master spreadsheet to be able to point to the new weekly data, everytime a new spreadsheet exists. So one would think to somehow make the vlookup *Table_Array* dynamic.
How do I accomplish this?

Additional note:- I have written a PowerShell script to output all the filenames & file extensions into a .csv file. Then I have created a macro to import the .csv data into a separate sheet in the master file. I did this as a potential lookup table. Example data below, we'll call it "Filename List":

`[SALES BY SKU STORE wk1 (retail)(2).xls]`

`[SALES BY SKU STORE wk2 (retail)(2).xls]`

`[SALES BY SKU STORE wk3 (retail)(2).xls]`

Solutions attempted but failed because my excel/macro/VBA knowledge is very limited:-

- The file destination does not change. The only part of the filename that changes is the week number. I have considered the idea of + 1 to the week number everytime a new file has been added to the Filename List. I don't know how to do any of this.
- I have tried the idea of `CONTCATENATE` with the *Table_Array* and the Filename List. Again, I don't know how to pull this off. Browsing the web has led me to believe `INDIRECT` is the way forward.
- The idea of writing `IF` statements via VBA code has come to mind. Potentially hardcoding the filenames in the vlookup, somehow. Again, I don't know how to do this.

Please can anyone shed some light as to how I do this? If you can answer with an idea, I will try my best to emulate it. I will appreciate anything at this point.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you not just create an additional workbook that is the latest file, then simply copy the new week's file over the top every time you get a new week's data? That way the formula won't need to change.

Comment: can you post the code you have put together? there are several ways to accomplish this, but without seeing how you are trying to work with it, it's hard to provide something that will fit as seamlessly as possible with your current code.

Comment: @Rory that is actually a good idea. However, automation is the key here. The less manual work for the users the better. - said my boss.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman the only code I have written is the vlookup. `=VLOOKUP(A2,'...OTC\2016\Reports Sent\[SALES BY SKU  STORE wk 3  (retail) (2).xls]SKU'!$D$1:$G$65536,4,FALSE)`

Comment: You can automate copying a file too... :)

Comment: @Rory So how do I automate copying the latest data? Remember, everytime a new spreadsheet exists, I need to automatically grab the data from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this - I've assumed you will never have more than 53 financial weeks:

```
Sub updateWorkbook()
    Dim n As Long
    Const csFOLDER_PATH As String = "C:\your path\"

    For n = 53 To 1 Step -1
        If Dir(csFOLDER_PATH & "SALES BY SKU STORE wk" & n & " (retail)(2).xls") <> vbNullString Then
            FileCopy csFOLDER_PATH & "SALES BY SKU STORE wk" & n & " (retail)(2).xls", csFOLDER_PATH & "SALES BY SKU STORE CURRENT (retail)(2).xls"
            Exit For
        End If
    Next n
End Sub
```

You can call this from the Open event of the master workbook. In the `ThisWorkbook` module, add:

```
Private Sub workbook_open
updateWorkbook
End Sub
```

Comment: I have adjusted the code to fit my folder path. Where do I place the code? Into a new VB `Module`, in the Sheet1 module or the ThisWorkbook module? Yes. I am a noob at this.

Comment: In a new module so it appears in your macros list.

Comment: I would have thought so. What is the trigger? How do I execute the code? When I find the macro in the Macro list under `updateWorkbook`, it does nothing when i run it.

Comment: You'll need to update your formulas to use SALES BY SKU STORE CURRENT (retail)(2).xls as the source file name, so that when the macro copies the latest week to that file, the formulas will update.

Comment: BTW, if you only have one external link in your master workbook, you could simply update that in code instead.

Comment: I totally acknowledge your second point. But the macro is not even copying and pasting anything. I've manually ran it and it simply does nothing leaving the sheet empty. The code specifies which file it is copying/pasting but it does not specify which sheet it is copying/pasting to/from?

Comment: It's copying an entire workbook to a new workbook, not a worksheet.

Comment: i have finally got this method to work. Jeez. How do i automate/schedule the macro/spreadsheet to run?

Comment: Thanks for the help @Rory. I have incorporated everything the way i want it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,INDIRECT("'...OTC\2016\Reports Sent\[SALES BY SKU  STORE wk " & A1 & " (retail) (2).xls]SKU'!$D$1:$G$65536"),4,FALSE)
```

where A1 is the week number you want to import the data from?

Comment: I will definitely give this a go. Thank you. I will report back.

Comment: @Rory yes. I have read about this. Which is why I felt iffy about using it. But I'll try it to see how it behaves.